# TDS 500 error, how do I test my TDS connection for more specific errors?

Tags: tds, visual-studio

Getting an HTTP 500 error in Team Development for Sitecore when syncing or doing any operation. How do I test my TDS connection for more specific errors?

Comment: Even though you could test the connection, this would not help you actually fix your 500 error.  You should check the output to actually resolve what's causing the 500 error to begin with.

Comment: The output was generic and not helpful, I got a proper error by testing the connection. Of course every error is different, but in my case the connection testing gave me the exact error I needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the specific errors as per your question you can try the below steps:

1. Select the output in Visual studio to get the details and see what happens when sync.
   [image]
2. Use the Test button for TDS specific project to validate the values you entered are correct.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Check for the logs in the Sitecore to see if you have any errors.
4. Last but not least make sure you are connected to the network like pulse secure or anything else which you are using for your connections.

Comment: This is great, I know all of this stuff but as a beginner it took me a long time to get up to speed, we need more answers like this. Path to sitecore logs: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SITE_NAME\App_Data\logs , would be nice to explain the different kinds of log files in another Q/A

Answer (score 0):

Right click any VS TDS project and click Properties. Select the "Build" tab, click the "Test" button at the end of the page.